# Artifactory Remote Repository with Azure DevOps - 404 error

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, artifactory

I am getting a `404 (Not Found)` when attempting to connect an Artifactory Remote Repository to an Azure DevOps NuGet feed.

The problem seems to lie in the URL and feed configuration fields. If I put https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/MyOrg in the URL field and then `_packaging/MyRepository/nuget/v2` in the "NuGet Download Context Path" or "NuGet Feed Context Path", the 404 error still persists. The only way I can avoid getting a 404 when testing the setup is to place the entire v3 URL into the "URL" field, like so:

https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/MyOrg/_packaging/MyRepository/nuget/v3/index.json

While this gets me through the configuration UI, I'll end up with `404 (Not Found)` errors when attempting to run `nuget install <package>` from the command line. For configuring the NuGet source locally, I simply copy-paste the command from the Artifactory UI.

What parameters need to go in the various fields for the Azure DevOps feed within Artifactory? Seems like this should be relatively straight-forward.